# How can I convert an icon to font awesome with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I made an icon with this JavaScript, but the icon can't be displayed, is there something wrong ?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let featuredFoods = document.querySelectorAll('.bintang');

  let starIcon = document.createElement('i');
  starIcon.classList.add('far.fa-star');

  featuredFoods.forEach((el) => {
      el.append(starIcon,starIcon,starIcon,starIcon,starIcon);
  })
})
```

Comment: `far.fa-star` is incorrect, change to `.add('far', 'fa-star');`

Comment: Use `el.append(starIcon);` five times rather than`el.append(starIcon,starIcon,starIcon,starIcon,starIcon);`

Comment: icon has appeared but only displays one icon.
I want in one div there are 5 icons,
maybe you can try to help, source code https://github.com/subkh4n/foodyar

Answer (score 2):

Just use a string for the star HTML, and then create a new array with five elements, and fill each element with a star icon making sure you create a string of HTML from the array with [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to use in the `innerHTML`.

```js
let featuredFoods = document.querySelectorAll('.bintang');

const starIcon = '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';

featuredFoods.forEach(el => {
  const stars = new Array(5).fill(starIcon).join('');
  el.innerHTML = stars;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bintang"></div>
<div class="bintang"></div>
<div class="bintang"></div>
<div class="bintang"></div>
<div class="bintang"></div>
```